# Visual studio cordova sign app

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm tring to make an app using visual studio 2015 and Cordova.
When I build the release everything works, but the distribution doesn't, and appear:

> The Android packages must be signed when you are debugging with configuration type version . To configure the signing Android , follow the instructions in http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613579

I cannot understand where is the error,

Thanks

UPDATE

now my build.json is:

```
{
    "android": {
        "release": {
            "keystore": "example.keystore",
            "storePassword": "example",
            "alias": "example",
            "password" : "example",
            "keystoreType": ""
         }
    }
 }
```

but when I try to build the release I have this

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\example\example\platforms\android\..\..\example.keystore
```

the keystore is in the folder  platform\android but i don't understand why there are \...\...\   I never add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to sign your application. Here are a couple links to help get you started:

- Android's documentation on signing your app. This probably should be your first stop, as it explains both the debug and release build signing process: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
- A Tutorial on signing your app for release distribution: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/signing-apache-cordova-android-app-release/

Comment: The keystore file path would be relative to the top level directory, not the platforms/android directory.